# Want to create an image of words that appear the most

Tags: html, image, html-parsing

I want to create one of these

[Click To See Image](http://images.google.com/imgres?q=words%20that%20appear%20the%20most&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=624&gbv=2&tbm=isch&tbnid=K7A_A7P6ZW_DJM%3a&imgrefurl=http://freelancetheology.com/2011/08/29/1-john-chapter-2-%25E2%2580%2593-if-you-know-god-then-you%25E2%2580%2599ll-love-each-other/&docid=9JyFjFZKPfMbqM&imgurl=http://freelancetheology.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/1-John-2-wordleweb.jpg&w=448&h=303&ei=heTeTr7wD6n20gGPqt2tBw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=368&vpy=152&dur=2052&hovh=185&hovw=273&tx=116&ty=94&sig=110825066536887775144&page=1&tbnh=120&tbnw=178&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0)

Im going to parse Html from a website and want to create they above with the words that appear most commonly.
Are their any libraries I can use or can someone point me in the right direction- Thanks Community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! http://www.wordle.net/